# Google Document AI Api integration in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloud-document-ai, google-cloud-ai

Have anyone integrated Cloud Document AI Api in ReactJs?
If so, what’s the way procedure of it’s integration?

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest

I didn’t found any proper way to integrate it in ReactJs.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't official documentation for React specifically, but you can refer to the [Node.js Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/documentai/latest) for more information about implementing in JavaScript.

This Sample Web Application was also built using React, so you can refer to it for examples.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/document-ai-samples/tree/main/document-json-explorer